# $\{(T(t)f)(s) \; ;\; t \geq 0\}$ is a $C_0$ semigroup

Tags: functional-analysis, semigroup-of-operators

Consider the Banach Space $$ X=\{f:\mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R} ; f \:\mbox{is bounded and uniformly continuous \} }$$
with norm $$||f||= \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} |f(x)|, \: \forall\: f\in X.$$

For $ f\in X$ define $$(T(t)f)(s)=f(t+s), \: \forall \:t\geq 0 \: \mbox{and} \: s\in\mathbb{R}.$$

I want to show that $\{T (t) \; ; \; t\geq 0 \}$ is a $C _0$ semigroup, in X. I managed to show all the conditions of the definition of $C _0$ a semigroup, except that
$$ T(t+\overline{s})f)(s)= T(t)f(s)\;T(\overline{s})f(s),\:\forall\:t,\overline{s}\geq0, f\in X, s\in\mathbb{R} ,$$
that is,
$$ f(t+\overline{s}+s)=f(t+s)\;f(s+\overline{s}),\:\forall\:t,\overline{s}\geq0, f\in X, s\in\mathbb{R}.$$

How to show it?

Comment: You are misstating the semigroup property. The correct property is $T(t+\bar s)f = T(t)T(\bar s) f$, no product on the right hand side. Now work out what this means for the argument $s \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: This was being my mistake then, misinterpreting the definition of $T(t) f$. Thank you!